# Как из словаря присваивать значения переменным?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, словарь

Имеется словарь который импортируется в файл json, а при запуске программы информация должна считываться, и помещаться в отдельные переменные, словарь:

```
save_data = dict(one = VVU, two = oil, three = money, four = inventory, five = bullets, six = hp, seven = event_home, eight = bochka, nine = kan)
```

Если заглянуть в json файл, то будет:

```
{"one": 0, "two": 0, "three": 0, "four": ["Винчестер"], "five": 20, "six": 30, "seven": 0, "eight": 0, "nine": 0}
```

Как каждое значние ("...": 0) именно 0 записать в отдельную переменную?

```
import json

path = 'save.json'

f1 = open(path, 'r')
DO = json.loads(f1.read())
f1.close()

VVU = 1 значение (на данный момент 0)
oil = 2 значение
money = 3 значение
inventory = 4 значение (Винчестер)
bullets = 5 значение
hp = 6 значение
event_home = 7 значение
bochka = 8 значение
kan = 9 значение
```

Comment: Зачем переменные? Что мешает вам работать со словарём?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev мне мешает то, что мне нужно эти переменные постоянно изменять, и придется переписывать половину кода

Comment: Лучше переписать. Динамически создавать переменные - это антишаблон.

Comment: а как вы собираетесь изменять переменные, которые создаются динамически? Во-первых, неизвестно, как они называются. Во-вторых, неизвестно сколько их и есть ли они вообще.

Comment: Как вы собираетесь работать с переменными? Вы же не знаете как их зовут. Идея переменной состоит в паре <фиксированное имя>/<меняющееся значение>. Если имя не фиксированно, то как этим пользоваться?

Comment: Ну и конечно переменная `json` напрочь развалит вашу программу.

Answer (score 0):

Соглашусь c @SergeyGornostaev, динамическая генерация переменных крайне не удачный вариант: отладка и поддержка кода со временем становятся крайне сложными, при неудачном стечении обстоятельств Вы можете переопределить любую переменную или зарезервированное слово.

Более корректный подход - использование словаря, либо собственного класса, который позволит реализовать требуемый функционал, при этом минимально повлияв на имеющуюся кодовую базу.

Однако, если необходимо на лету создавать переменные, то одним из вариантов является использование exec():

```
    save_data = {"one" : "VVU", "two" : "oil", "three" : 'money'}
    json_data = {"one": 0, "two": 0, "three": 0}
    for key in save_data.keys():
        exec("{0} = {1}".format(key, json_data[key]))

    >>> one
```

Перед использованием настоятельно рекомендую ознакомиться с документацией, т.к. это достаточно не безопасная вещь.

Comment: Зачем `exec`? Работайте с `locals`.